# Adjust matplotlib RadioButtons font size

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget

I wonder if anyone has an advice on how to adjust the font size on the `RadiouButtons` side text. Taking the [widget example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/radio_buttons.html) from matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s0 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s1 = np.sin(4*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.sin(8*np.pi*t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l, = ax.plot(t, s0, lw=2, color='red')
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
rax = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.7, 0.15, 0.15], facecolor=axcolor)
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('2 Hz', '4 Hz', '8 Hz'))


def hzfunc(label):
    hzdict = {'2 Hz': s0, '4 Hz': s1, '8 Hz': s2}
    ydata = hzdict[label]
    l.set_ydata(ydata)
    plt.draw()
radio.on_clicked(hzfunc)

rax = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.15, 0.15], facecolor=axcolor)
radio2 = RadioButtons(rax, ('red', 'blue', 'green'))


def colorfunc(label):
    l.set_color(label)
    plt.draw()
radio2.on_clicked(colorfunc)

rax = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.15], facecolor=axcolor)
radio3 = RadioButtons(rax, ('-', '--', '-.', ':'))


def stylefunc(label):
    l.set_linestyle(label)
    plt.draw()
radio3.on_clicked(stylefunc)

plt.show()
```

[image]

How could I make "2Hz, 4Hz, 8Hz" larger?

It is possible to adjust the buttons size by accessing the `Circle` objects on the `RadioButtons`. Is there something similar to the font size? (the [buttons](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/buttons.html) widget have the `.label.set_fontsize()` attribute but I have not found a similar thing for this widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the font size of the `RadioButton` labels you need to access the properties of the individual label:

```py
for r in radio.labels: r.set_fontsize(16)
```